# React 0.12.2: "Error: Lower case component names (paper-button) are no longer supported in JSX"

Tags: polymer, reactjs, web-component, custom-element

I am trying to use a web component ([paper-icon-button](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-icon-button)) in a React component and I am getting the following error:

`Error: Lower case component names (paper-button) are no longer supported in JSX" error: See http://fb.me/react-jsx-lower-case`

As of React 0.12, all lower-case tag names are interpreted as DOM elements vs. React components, so this should work:

```
<paper-icon-button className="red" icon="favorite"></paper-icon-button>
```

However, I am noticing that the following condition is still included the current versions of `/node_modules/react/dist/JSXTransformer.js` and `/node_modules/react-tools/vendor/fbtransform/transforms/react.js`:

```
// Identifiers with lower case or hypthens are fallback tags (strings).
  // XJSMemberExpressions are not.
  if (nameObject.type === Syntax.XJSIdentifier && isTagName(nameObject.name)) {
    // This is a temporary error message to assist upgrades
    if (!FALLBACK_TAGS.hasOwnProperty(nameObject.name)) {
      throw new Error(
        'Lower case component names (' + nameObject.name + ') are no longer ' +
        'supported in JSX: See http://fb.me/react-jsx-lower-case'
      );
    }
```

This comment `// This is a temporary error message to assist upgrades` seems to convey that this is just an informative message, but it's breaking my app's Grunt workflow. How can I use custom elements/web components with react@^0.12?

My project:

I am receiving the error when running my grunt-browerify tasks with the `options: { transform: [require('grunt-react').browserify] }` option. This is what I have in my package.json:

```
...
"grunt-browserify": "^3.3.0",
"grunt-react": "^0.10.0",
"react": "^0.12.2",
"node-jsx": "^0.12.4"
...
```

Comment: Commenting out the following worked: if (!FALLBACK_TAGS.hasOwnProperty(nameObject.name)) {
      throw new Error(
        'Lower case component names (' + nameObject.name + ') are no longer ' +
        'supported in JSX: See http://fb.me/react-jsx-lower-case'
      );
    }

Comment: Andrew Rota says that a fix is coming and may be available in 0.13.0-alpha.1 or greater: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2746#issuecomment-76260575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in React.js 0.13.0-alpha.1 or higher since [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2830) was merged.  Upgrading to 0.13 should remove the warning.

Comment: Sadly, on React 14.3 and still no fix. I'd go with @senornestor's suggestion